# Invalidate Square Checkout URL

Tags: c#, square

Is there a way to invalidate a Square Checkout URL that was generated using the Square Checkout API? My current C# project calls the Checkout API using the square dotnet SDK and waits for the user to pay, and then commences after the payment is completed. I don't want the possibility of the user not completing the order and never being redirected to the confirmation URL, so I want to implement a timeout where if the user doesn't pay within a specific amount of time, the entire transaction is canceled. Here is my description in pseudocode:

```
URL = CallCheckoutAPI(locationId, order);
OpenBrowser(URL);
Success = WaitForPayment(timeoutDuration); //Returns true if payment completes,
                                           //false on timeout
if (Success) Commence();
else CancelTransaction(); //This is where the invalidation of the URL would happen
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The checkout URL will still be valid for 180 days. However, if the user never got access to the checkout url, then they won't be able to find it since it's a unique URL. There's no way to cancel the checkout URL, though.